# Convergence almost surely to zero

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Some number of shares are bought at the moment zero, and the portfolio does not change on $[0, ... ,N]$. At any moment $n = 1...N$ a price of these shares may independently go up $80\%$ with probability $p = \frac{1}{2}$ or go down $60\%$. Prove that for any initial investment $X_0$ its price $X_N$ at the moment $N$ converges almost surely to $0$ when $N \to \infty$.

I tried to apply here a corollary of the Borel-Cantelli lemma: if for $\varepsilon > 0$ $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P\left[X_{n}>\epsilon\right]<\infty \Rightarrow X_n \stackrel{a.s}{\longrightarrow} 0$$ From Markov inequality $$P\left[X_{n}>\epsilon\right] \leq \frac{E[X_n]}{\varepsilon}$$ $$E[X_n] = \sum\limits_{i = 0}^n {n\choose i} p^i (1-p)^{n-i} \cdot X_0 (1.8)^i (0.4)^{n-i} = X_0 \cdot (1.4p + 0.4)^n$$ This estimate does not give the convergence of the series above. Please give me a hint so that i can proceed further.

Thank you!

Comment: Hmm... I don't believe the statement is true for all $p > 0.5$. Are you sure it is written correctly?

Comment: To be honest, this also seems strange to me. However, my lecturer insists that this is true. What do you think about the case $p=0.5$?

Comment: For $p = 0.5$, you will have a fair coin toss game, where with each head toss you receive 80% of your capital and with each tail toss you lose 60% of you capital. Do you think you will almost surely lose your initial capital in you play this game long enough? I think you went the right way by applying Borel-Cantelli lemma and Markov's inequality. From that, you can obtain the range for $p$, for which $X_N$ converges to zero a.s..